# Non significant interaction in a 2X2 ANOVA but significant t-test

Tags: anova, interaction

I have a within-subject design and I analysed the data by using a 2X2 repeated-measures ANOVA. My dependent variable is continuous and my two independent variables are categorical. Assume that the two independent variables are Outcome (Win/Lose) and Condition (Individual/Social). I obtained two main effects (for Outcome, p = .000, for Condition, p = 0.03) and no interaction. This suggests that Outcome has an effect on my dependent variable independently of Condition and that Condition has an effect on my dependent variable independently of Outcome. I am aware that I should not run post-hoc comparisons or t-test when no interaction is present. However, if I run a paired t-test, I see that Condition is only significant when participants lose (collapsing all the lose trials across conditions) and not when participants win (collapsing all the win trials across conditions). Given that, I would expect that the interaction is also significant. I would be grateful if you can help me to understand this. Thanks